# Excel Column AutoFit Frustration

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

While working in Excel, I'm encountering an issue with column width adjustment. Manually double-clicking each column to fit the content is becoming tedious, especially with a large dataset spanning over 1000 columns. Is there an option or shortcut to automatically adjust the width of all columns at once for a more efficient workflow?

i've tried clicking adjusting the length of the column, and double clicking it

Comment: You can select all the columns and double-click once to adjust them all at once. Next, try to figure out what madness is giving you 1000 columns to look at in a worksheet and stop it.

Comment: Upvoted the comment above especially on the second argument. Shouldn't the columns be rows maybe?